# Syslog-ng: how to log severity/facility?

Tags: sles, sles10, syslog-ng

**Here is the system:**

- SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10
- syslog-ng with predefined syslog-ng.conf
- messages in /var/log/messages look like:

Feb  8 09:29:53 sles1 sshd[17529]: Accepted keyboard-interactive/pam for root from 10.30.34.64 port 4855 ssh2

**What I need:**

- to log event severity/facility. For instance, add **<PRI>** at the beginning of the message:

**<15>** Feb  8 09:29:53 sles1 sshd[17529]: Accepted keyboard-interactive/pam for root from 10.30.34.64 port 4855 ssh2

**My question is:**

**How to change syslog-ng.conf to enable this kind of logging?**

Thanks.

Comment: see a good answer here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/680490/162125

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want to [rewrite your logfiles in a specific format](http://www.campin.net/syslog-ng/faq.html#template).  The link has the details on how to tell syslog-ng to do that :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on some quick reading I think you want to use the syslog() driver, which si described in section 8.1.6 of the Syslog-ng Administrator's guide.  http://www.balabit.com/support/documentation/?product=syslog-ng

I hope this helps, if I find anything more, I'll let you know.

I think the syslog() driver is meant to be used with the source declaration.  so where I have `source external { udp(); };`

You might use `source external { syslog(transport("udp")); };`

I don't have a suitable testing environment to try this out on, but I think this is what you want to do, if I understand your question correctly.

---

I went back and looked and it turns out there's a macro you can use in your destination called TAG e.g.

```
destination d_all {
    file("/log/$FACILITY.log" group("users")
    template_escape(no)
    template("$TAG $PRIORITY $S_DATE $HOST $MSG\n"));
};
```

These macros are defined around page 218 of the admin guide.

Comment: Truth be told, I failed to find any real-life example of changes you need to make for this stuff.

Comment: Actually, I don't have source external { udp(); }; in my config. What I have is slightly different:
source src {
        internal();
        unix-dgram("/dev/log");
};

Comment: The $PRIORITY will contain both severity and facility. You better to use `${SEVERITY}`.
But easier would be just to use `flags("syslog-protocol")`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a destination configured as so:

```
destination syslog-consumer { unix-stream("/var/run/syslog-output"); };
```

syslog messages headed to `syslog-consumer` get sent to that socket in the format you want.

You'll just need to setup something to listen to that socket and write to a file.

Comment: Is there some other way without listening to the socket? I wonder why can't I add something to this declaration ...
destination messages { file("/var/log/messages"); };
log { source(src); filter(f_messages); destination(messages); };
... to add <PRI> field in /var/log/messages...

Comment: I posted this particular method since my log consumer just listened to the socket without any intermediate files. Thought it might fit your need :)